# In MongoDB, Java driver how to use "explain" with aggregate?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

In MongoDB **Java** driver how to use the "explain" option ?

```
db.orders.aggregate([
      { $match: { status: "A" } },
      { $sort: { total: -1 } }
   ],
   { explain: true }
)
```

`Collection.aggregate()` does not accept options

```
orders.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
    Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("status","A")),         
    Aggregates.sort(Sorts.descending("total"))
))
```

Comment: I think that's impossible with Java Driver.

Answer (score 2):

You can fall back to [runCommand](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.11/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoDatabase.html#runCommand(org.bson.conversions.Bson)) and use the [explain command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/#dbcmd.explain) that way.

Something along the lines of

```
db.runCommand(new Document(myMap))
```

where myMap is (writing in JSON)

```
{"explain": {"aggregate": "my.collection", "pipeline": [{"$project": {"_id": 1}}]}}
```